# The "unsigned" keyword

Tags: c++, unsigned

I saw in some C++ code the keyword "unsigned" in the following form:

```
const int HASH_MASK = unsigned(-1) >> 1;
```

and later:

```
unsigned hash = HASH_SEED;
```

(it is taken from the CS106B/X reader - of Stanford - by Eric S. Roberts - on the topic of "implementation of the hash code function for strings").

Can someone tell me please what does that keyword mean and when do I use it anyway?

Thanks!

Comment: Already answered here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621290/what-is-the-difference-between-signed-and-unsigned-variables

Comment: `const int HASH_MASK = MAX_INT;` seems like a better bet to me.  Or I guess maybe `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` in C++?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7176690/1758762

> unsigned is a modifier which can apply to any integral type (char,
>   short, int, long, etc.) but on its own it is identical to unsigned
>   int.

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/q/336/1758762

Answer (score 0):

It's a short version of `unsigned int`. Syntactically, you can use it anywhere you would use any other datatype like `float` or `short`.

Answer (score 0):

Unsigned types are types that can't represent negative numbers; only zero and positive numbers. In C++, they use modular arithmetic; the modulus for an `N`-bit type is `2^N`. It's a good idea to use unsigned rather than signed types when messing around with bit patterns (for example, when calculating hash codes), since C++ allows several different representations of negative numbers which could lead to portability issues.

`unsigned` can be used as a qualifier for any integer type (e.g. `unsigned int` or `unsigned long long`); or on its own as shorthand for `unsigned int`.

So the first converts `-1` into `unsigned int`. Due to modular arithmetic, this gives the largest representable value. This could also be written (more clearly, in my opinion) as `std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()`.

The second declares and initialises a variable of type `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 0):

Values are signed by default, which means they can be positive or negative. The unsigned keyword is used to specify that a value must be positive.

Signed variables use 1 bit to specify whether the value is positive or not. The unsigned keyword actualy makes this bit part of the value (thus allowing bigger numbers to be stored).

Lastly, `unsigned hash` is interpreted by compilers as `unsigned int hash` (int being the default type in C programming).

Answer (score 0):

To get a good idea what unsigned means, one has to understand signed and unsigned integers.  For a full explanation of twos-compliment, search Wikipedia, but in a nutshell, a computer stores negative numbers by subtracting negative numbers from 2^32 (for a 32-bit integer).  In this way, -1 is stored as 2^32-1.  This does mean that you only have 2^31 positive numbers, but that is by the by.  This is known as **signed integers** (as it can have positive or negative sign)

Unsigned tells the compiler that you don't want twos compliment and are dealing only in positive numbers.  When -1 is typecast (as it is in the code) to an **unsigned int** it becomes

```
2^32-1 = 0b111111111...
```

Thus that is an easy way of getting a whole lot of 1s in binary.

Use unsigned rarely.  If you need to do bit operations, or for some reason need only positive integers bigger than 2^31.  Otherwise, if you leave it out, c++ assumes signed integers.

Answer (score 0):

C allows `char`s to be signed or unsigned, depending on which is more efficient for the host computer. if you want to be sure your `char` is unsigned, you can declare your variable to be `unsigned char`. You can use `signed char` if you want the ensure signed interpretation.

Incidentally, the C and C++ compilers treatd `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` as three distinct types, even though `char` is compiled into one of the other two.