# Not understanding the output

Tags: c

```
main()
{
    unsigned x=1;
    signed char y=-1;
    if(x>y)
        printf("x>y");
    else
        printf("x<=y");
}
```

output is: x<=y

But my question is in the statement unsigned x=1; there is no data type such as int or char.  So what will the compiler assume? And in the statement signed char y=-1; Isn't it a error? and i also want to know how the program works.

Comment: 1. `unsigned int`; 2. no, it isn't; 3. it works very well.

Comment: possible duplicate: [The “unsigned” keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16568382/1825094) (What does `unsigned` without a specific type mean?)

Comment: to assign characters to variable we follow i.e char y='z'. so how -1 can be stored in y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
signed char y=-1;
```

-1 is generally stored in `2's` complement form, but `y` is interpreted as positive. So `y` becomes a very large value, which is always greater than `x`.

---

Even if it's stored is sign+magnitude form, It is still a very large value, if treated as positive. And 1's complement complement of -1 is also greater than 1, if interpreted as positive value.

Comment: How do you know it **will** be stored in 2's complement? It could be stored as 1's complement and in sign+magnitude representation as well.

Comment: Those are spelled "interpreted" and "positive". With "e" and **one** "s".

Comment: what is sign+magnitude?

Comment: In signed magnitude form a negative number is stored with most significant bit 1. And that bit is reserved for sign (i.e. negative-1, positive-0)

Answer (score 3):

The default type for a "naked" `unsigned` is `unsigned int`.

The comparison works thanks to C's arithmetic promotions, which will convert both arguments to `>` to a suitable type before doing the comparison.

Comment: How wii the conversion work@unwind

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the storage mechanism of the system.

Please check the following code where the o/p is shown in hex [direct storage format], for sake of simplicity.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        unsigned int ua = 1;
        signed int sa = -1;
        if (ua>sa)
                printf("ua>sa\n");
        else
                printf("sa>ua\n");

        printf("unsigned = 0x%x\t signed = 0x%x\n", ua, sa);

        return 0;
}
```

output:

```
[sourav@localhost Practice]# ./a.out 
sa>ua
unsigned = 0x1   signed = 0xffffffff
[sourav@localhost Practice]#
```

Hope this helps.